# What strategy should I use for multiple room booking selection without JS?

Tags: user-interface, accessibility, javascript

The user requests 2 rooms on the initial page and is then presented with room types to select from on step 2. The arriving and starting dates will *always* be the same, but the number of adults and children may differ, causing the price to fluctuate.

Now, if JS is enabled I think I'll just program it such that it's tab-powered and when you hit 'Select' which is an input submit, it'll cancel the form submit and mimic a "add to cart" functionality, so the user *must* select at least one room for each specified.

I'm confused on how I should treat this with JS off - should I just enable radio buttons or checkboxes and have the user select with radio buttons per room? So instead of "Select" button image it would be just a label "Select this" text and a radio button nearby, and at the far bottom of my form there will be one primary submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just not providing a non-JS alternative.